# Cannot change href value using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I cannot change anchor tag attribute value using jquery, I cannot figure out what is the problem. I'm sharing my code

HTML:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-success="onDeleteSuccess" href="/ShoppingCart/AddToCart" id="url">Add to cart</a>
```

Jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#qty').on("mouseout keydown mouseover", (function() {
        if ($('#product-quantity').val() <= 0) {
            $('#product-quantity').val(1);
        }
        var triming = $('#pricetxt').text().replace('$', '');
        var price = parseInt(triming);
        var qty = $('#product-quantity').val();
        var res = price * qty;
        var b = $('#product-quantity').val();
        $('#write').text(b + ' quantity' + ' X ' + price + ' price = $' + res);
        $('#url').attr("href", '/ShoppingCart/AddToCart/3019' + '?qty=' + b);
    }));
});
```

It is not changing `href` value and I need to change it on keydown and mouseover events.

Comment: I'd say it's because the line does not get executed. do you have monitored the function with a console (such as firebug's?). Also how do you figure it does not change?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier yes everything is working perfect only the last line of script is not working

Comment: then if it's working perfectly why are you asking question?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier it is not working with href attribute, it is not changing href value

Comment: That is why I ask if you have reviewed this on a console? How do you know the rest is working correctly? Anyway try using `.prop` instead of `.attr`.

Comment: working fine ...  http://jsfiddle.net/ea43B/

Comment: @Runcorn it is working in fiddle but not working in my page :(

Comment: If then ,  you can update thee result., fiddle with your own code .. and see the result. If issue persist then show us the console log.

Comment: @Runcorn thanks, how i can show u the console?

Comment: in any browser , right click >> inspect element >> Console tab. It will show you the error if there are any. Shortcut F12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With jQuery 1.6 and above you should use

```
$("#url").prop("href", "http://www.jakcms.com")
```

The difference between prop and attr is that attr grabs the HTML attribute where as prop grabs the DOM property.